# How can I compare column values from two different work sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have two different Worksheets (A and B), both of which contains the columns `PackageName` and `PackageVersion`, both `Column B` and `Column C` respectively in each worksheet. I would like to have a third worksheet (C) where I can use Column B as the key and display data where Column C is not the same in worksheets A and B.

Example from Worksheet A:

[image: Worksheet A]

Example from worksheet B:

[image: Worksheet B]

Goal: Display this in Worksheet C

[Worksheet C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9kw3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised there has been no answer yet to this question as it is a pretty easy thing to do.

You have two issues to deal with information-wise. One is if you find a match for a Worksheet B item on Worksheet A. In that case, you need to compare the PackageVersion values for Match or No Match. If you do not find the Worksheet B item on Worksheet A at all, you need to simply output No Match. Alongside the main show, you also need to populate the PackageName column for Worksheet C.

To do the latter, simply place the following in cell B2, then copy and paste down enough cells to bring in all of the column on Worksheet B's entries. If it has 1,134, then copy it down 1,134 cells on Worksheet C. Nothing interesting, but it is the simplest formulaic way to achieve it. Prefer something without a formula? Just select all the entries on Worksheet B, copy them to the Clipboard, then paste them into the right place on Worksheet C.

To do the comparisons, use the following formula in the PackageVersion column for Worksheet C, editing references as needed for your precise details, and copying it down however many cells you need to to match the PackageName column:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B2,'Worksheet A'!B2:C1135,2,FALSE)=VLOOKUP(B2,'Worksheet B'!B2:C1135,2,FALSE),"Match","NoMatch"),"NoMatch")
```

Inside the formula, you set up an `IF()` test comparing the values you need from each sheet to each other. If it succeeds (is `TRUE`), it results in the word "Match" and if it fails because it finds both, but they do not match, it results in "NoMatch". If it did not find the item in the PackageName column on BOTH sheets, then it errors out, but the `IFERROR()` outside that sees that happen and does a different thing than return the error as a result:  instead it returns "NoMatch".

It is written for the data being 1,134 rows in columns B and C on each worksheet, A and B. Change addresses as you need to, of course.

Notice that it looks at its own column B cell for what to look up on each sheet. That might be a smidge slower for Excel since it has to update that cell before it can pass that value to the formula. Since you are looking up information on Worksheet B, you could actually use its B2:B1135 cells directly so there's slightly less calculating. Not really an issue nowadays, but something to remember for future uses, maybe.

Also, if you are interested, there are other ways to do the lookup. This works nicely, but some people would hate on you if you use `VLOOKUP()` rather than `INDEX/MATCH`. And if anyone using the spreadsheet is on an updated version of Excel, you can use the `XLOOKUP` function if you prefer. The latter is as easy to understand as `VLOOKUP()` is, and while it cannot replace the other lookups for all situations, it certainly can for this situation.